# Get slot from containing object in nested object

Tags: iolanguage

I have a set of nested objects, and need to get a slot from the containing object. Can it be done?

Example:

```
Foo := Object clone do(
    a := "hello"

    Bar := Object clone do(
        b := Foo a  # How to get `Foo a` here?
    )
)
```

From the above code, I get an exception in the nested object `Bar` when accessing `Foo`:

```
Exception: Object does not respond to 'Foo'
```

---

The reason I would like to have these as nested objects, is because it would make it easier (IMO) to make the application more modular. If it was possible I could easily do something like

```
Foo := Object clone do(
    someSlot := "Some value"

    Bar := doRelativeFile("./folder/bar.io")
)
```

and in `folder/bar.io` use `Foo someSlot` if needed.

Think of e.g. `someSlot` as a database connection, and `Bar` as a data-model needing that database connection.

Comment: `Foo` hasn't been assigned yet when you evaluate it. Maybe create a getter? Reminds me of the [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572) in JavaScript - with similar solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by creating an `intialize` method in the nested object, which takes the containing object as a parameter and returns `self` (i.e. the nested object.

So I can have two files like this:

1. `a.io`

   ```
   Foo := Object clone do(
       foo := "foobar"

       Bar := doRelativeFile("./b.io") initialize(thisContext)
   )
   ```
2. `b.io`

   ```
   Bar := Object clone do(
       initialize := method(parent,
           writeln("parent foo is ", parent foo)
           return self
       )
   )
   ```

While not a perfect solution, it should work well enough for my purposes.

Comment: We usually call this a `with` method for this case.